# Тепло и теплота

Tags: грамотная-речь

Речь сейчас не о физическом понятии теплоты, а о характеристике отношения к чему-то. Так вот, если ли разница в выражениях "Относиться к нему с теплом" и "Относиться к нему с теплотой"? И если да, то какое выражение правильнее?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не вижу принципиальной разницы. Оба варианта правильные.
Кстати, физическое толкование тоже, вроде бы, не делает принципиальных различий между терминами.

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, грамотная конструкция "относиться как?", а не "с чем?", поэтому правильно говорить: "тепло отношусь к нему". В физике (термодинамике) доминирует понятие "теплота".